# Grab a particular object property instead of direct referencing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to grab a particular object property in my checkForUrgentEvents method and return it. Instead of referencing it the way I'm currently doing is there a way to look for a particular property? I tried Object.hasownproperty but since it's deeply nested it didn't work.

```
  private checkForUrgentEvents(urgentEventsData: any, query:CurrentContentParams) {
  return urgentEventsData.data.Data[
      query.type + caasConfig.urgentContentIdSuffix
    ].content[query.id];

  }


// urgentEventsData:

{ status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers:
   { connection: 'close',
     'transfer-encoding': 'chunked' },
  config:
   { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
     transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
     transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
     timeout: 0,
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     method: 'get',
  data:
   { LatestModified: 1555080079154,
     Results: 1,
     Error: '',
     Data: { faqsurgentcontent: [Object] } } }

//query:
{ id: 'MAIN', type: 'faqs' }
```

Comment: where is MAIN and faqs in your object?

Comment: query.id is MAIN and query.type is faqs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar problem, follow this:

```
 parseContentResponse(response: any, scope: string, type: string) {
    if (response) {
      return (
        this.getContentObject(
          response,
          ['data', 'Data', `${scope}`, 'content', `${type}`]
        )
      );
    }
    return response;
  }

//then you could look for the key

 private getContentObject(response: any, contentPathArray: Array<string>) {
    return contentPathArray.reduce(
      (obj, key) => (obj && obj[key] !== 'undefined' ? obj[key] : undefined),
      response
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function findById(o, id) {
    //Early return
    if( o.id === id ){
    return o;
    }
    var result, p; 
    for (p in o) {
        if( o.hasOwnProperty(p) && typeof o[p] === 'object' ) {
            result = findById(o[p], id);
            if(result){
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: But can we apply this in the current context? as the query contains id as well as the type